# How to get notification subscriptions in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I want to trigger VERY basic push notifications, but, don't see any way to iterate through all the subscribed users, without rolling my own tool to read the db notification_user table.  Surely, with such an extensive (and expensive) product such as Worklight there is an API to do this?

The only way I see is within my adapter to call another HTTP adapter (go get the user subscriptions).  And, I've tried using the HTTP interface to retrieve the subscribed users via:

```
http://<server:port>/<context>/console/api/push/get?adapterName=PushAdapter&eventSource=EventSource
```

and many variations, but, nothing seems to work through browser testing (the doc indicates all are GET requests).  There are NO examples of how the "Push, Event Sources" (?) format for the api is (should the "API Context" value be "Push", or "EventSources", what?).  The chart given in the Worklight 6.0 Information Center is pretty bare minimum (how difficult would it have been to include an example of each?)

Basically, I want to iterate through a specific adapter/event source in a WL adapter, grab the "options" that were passed in when the user subscribed to perform some business logic on whether to send out a notification.  Would think this would be a very common pattern, but, don't see any examples of this type of model.

Anyone have suggestions for similar processing with WL 6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong. Worklight has 3 methods to send out notifications to subscribed users/devices

See

- [WL.Server.notifyAllDevices](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_notifyalldevi.html)
- [WL.Server.notifyDevice](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_notifydevice.html)
- [WL.Server.notifyDeviceSubscription](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_notifydevices.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I know about these methods, but, to use all of them you need to know get each subscribed user.  My question asks 1) must you use the http api to get them (or direct db access, which is very kludgy for a product as extensive as this), and 2) what is the correct url to get the subscribed users.

Comment: The first two methods take a user subscription as an argument. The last one takes a device subscription as an argument. 

To get a user subscription, you can use `WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription`  and to fetch a device subscription, you can use its counterpart `WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription.getDeviceSubscriptions`

Comment: I don't know the user(s) in this scenario, so I can't use any of these methods.  The notifyDeviceSubscriptions requires a subscription object, and, I can't get a subscription object without a userid (getDeviceSubscriptions is called on the user subscription object), so, I can't use this method.

Comment: And, whoever put a down vote on my question obviously doesn't know enough about Worklight to see that the doc is inadequate and/or incorrect for the http api.  Stackoverflow.